# How to sync tasks between Ubuntu and Android?

Tags: software-recommendation, android, task-management

I was using first Tasque and then GTG on Ubuntu and Astrid on Android with Remember The Milk as the backend. Recently, Astrid has dropped support for Remember The Milk, and both Tasque and GTG's support for syncing with RTM has always left something to be desired. So I'm looking for a new solution, and I'm open to leaving RTM especially if it is for something that isn't proprietary.

What have you found to keep your tasks lists in-sync between Ubuntu and Android?

In particular, I'm looking for a *desktop based* program on the Ubuntu side rather than something in the browser. Astrid has treated me well, but I wouldn't mind trying something else. Currently, it can sync with Astrid.com, Google Tasks, and Producteev. Anyone know of a desktop app that supports any of those?

Comment: Posting as a comment because [Epistle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kooklab.epistle) isn't a task manager, but it is what I use for the same purpose. It's a dead-simple way to sync text via a DropBox account. I access the notes via the DropBox appindicator from the desktop, and a launcher shortcut from my Android mobile. Sync works very reliably and is instant and very simple.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: Why is it "flagged for closure?" It still seems like a very reasonable question despite the fact that it hasn't been answered. It's received up votes. No one has voted to close it so far. What are the grounds for closing it?

Comment: As mentioned, there are a tons of great Android apps for syncing with Google tasks...the hard part is Ubuntu which just doesn't have the rich collection of apps that Android does. I punted on getting a real desktop solution in Ubuntu and went with Google Tasks Offline app in Chrome. Works great, looks good, works off line. Done. Still holding out hope that Thunderbird will sync with google tasks someday.

Answer (score 3):

deckoff hinted at this in his answer, and I've been trying it out myself for a bit now. So I should probably add it here. There is a GTasks indicator available in a third party PPA, google-tasks-indicator.

[image: google-tasks-indicator]

You can add the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/atareao) and install the app with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-tasks-indicator
```

It does most every thing that you expect, but you can't indent tasks and getting to notes is a bit inconvenient.

More and more, I'm thinking that GTasks just isn't feature-full enough for me...

Comment: I became very interested on GTD methodology and I've spent more than 2 hour trying to find a good app sync tasks between Ubuntu and Android. Please recommend one if you have found a good one. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I will simply go with Gtask chrome app for desktop and Gtasks in Android (though many different will do). Best way to do anything on Android is to do it via Google services -IMHO. If you still insist on desktop app, not in-browser app,  [look here](http://namsisi.wordpress.com/2009/02/22/gmail-tasks-in-your-ubuntu-system-tray/) ,  [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1886844), [or here](http://ubuntuinthewild.blogspot.com/2012/03/google-tasks-indicator-for-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Tomdroid, have used it for maybe a year now and is a really handy way to sync your Tomboy notes to your phone. Its [available in the Play store](http://goo.gl/kTl7n):

Description:

> Note-taking application with online synchronization compatible with
>   Tomboy A Tomboy client for Android.Tomboy is a desktop note-taking app
>   using a wikiwiki approach and a simple user interface. NOTE: It is a
>   READ-ONLY client for now.
>
> - Note format compatibility with Tomboy
> - Online note synchronization with Snowy, Tomboy Online or Ubuntu One
> - SD Card importation
> - Open source!

As an alternative you could use [Scratchpad](http://goo.gl/VkaDG) for Google Chrome. Then install the [Google Drive](http://goo.gl/WzeQN) app for your phone. I know it is browser based, but this should work with Google Tasks and works well if you want to edit your notes on your phone, but I find it slow compared to Tomdroid (but as you can see Tomdroid might not have all the functionality you would like).

Answer (score 0):

If your needs are simple (no recurring task, no much labeling) you can use [Wunderlist](http://www.wunderlist.com/). It has a Android client, web client and a Ubuntu client (available from the Software Center for 11.04 and 10.10).

For newer versions you will need some [tricks](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/how-to-install-wunderlist-in-ubuntu.html) to install it.

Comment: BTW, I use RTM as Wunderlist is to simple (I need recurring tasks). I have a pro (paid) account so I can use the official Android app, which is great, I use the browser on my laptop and I'm working in a Ubuntu client, but it's far from finished.

Answer (score 0):

I use Fruux for my calendar and todo list.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/527260)

Comment: Actually it does answer the question.  The fruux calendar and tasks sync with Evolution and Thunderbird.  Their android app syncs with Android.

Answer (score 0):

A recent option is to use [Trello](https://trello.com) web application and its [android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trello) and even more options of applications like [Terllo widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oryanmat.trellowidget)

It is not a native application for Ubuntu, as it is a web based solution however still provide a more intuitive way for managing your tasks and even share it with others.

**Update**
I found out a native client at [trello-desktop git repo](https://github.com/danielchatfield/trello-desktop) and a description for its setup and an image of it from [this blog](https://medium.com/@davideiaiunese/how-to-install-trello-on-ubuntu-754e9d8b4d03). I tried it and it works fine with me.